# How to increase Bootstrap column gap in a row beyond .g-5 with Vanilla CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Am building a simple landing page using bootstrap. I need to increase column gap in the row. I know we can increase the gap by customizing sass spacing mixin but since website am building includes couple of sections I want to keep it simple without build process. I have used g-5 classname on row which gives like 32px or 40px gap between columns. How to increase it further using CSS.

```
 <div class="container mt-5 pt-5">
      <div class="row text-light g-5 fs-1">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="bg-dark p-5">column</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="bg-dark p-5">column</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="bg-dark p-5">column</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```